# Weird result with Requests library to do web page login

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

I'm trying to use the session object in Requests library to make POST requests with login credential by following a practice example from the book "Web Scraping with Python". However, I have encountered a weird problem (probably a bug) with it. The author of the book had set up a simple login web page for test:
http://pythonscraping.com/pages/cookies/login.html.
The username can be anything with the password as "password", then the login process will be redirected to another page:
http://pythonscraping.com/pages/cookies/welcome.php.

The Python code that I use to run against it is as follows:

```
import requests
ssn = requests.Session()
param = {'password':'password','username':'letmein'}
r = ssn.post('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/cookies/welcome.php',data=param)
print('Cookies set to :')
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
print('Server response :')
print(r.text)
```

And the output of the above code is:

```
Cookies set to :
{'loggedin': '1', 'username': 'letmein'}
Server response :
<h2>Welcome to the Website!</h2>
Whoops! You logged in wrong. Try again with any username, and the password "password"    <br><a href="login.html">Log in here</a>
```

Apparently the login has failed. The thing that I don't understand is why. And in the program output showed the POST variables set by the request, the password variable is missing. Am I missing something here or is it a bug with the Requests library?

P.S. I'm running the program with Python 3.6.2 and Requests 2.18.4.

Comment: Trying to login through a browser results in the same message. The requests library doesn't seem to have a bug.

Comment: @LokeshA.R. Hmm.... That's weird. I have tried it with browser too and it works without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried logging in using browser. Apparently the password is **"password"** not **password** . Starting and ending quotes is part of password.

I think @PRMoureu is wrong in suggesting that url should be of login. Actually url should be http://pythonscraping.com/pages/cookies/welcome.php only. Because actual login functionality is implemented on this page.

Comment: Are you sure ? i cannot see any input field on this page

Comment: Hmm.... @imox I don't think the double quotes are included in the password. I tried the login with web browser without those quotes in the password and it works correctly.

Comment: @Hapsburg I swear, I am pretty sure it worked for me with only double quotes

Comment: @Prm actually those are parameters that the welcome. Php need to login the user. Those parameter exist on the login page so we are taking them from them and asking welcome page to work it's logic. If you are loging in from Web browser you will need to go login page but using python you can directly pass username and password to welcome page. Same would be done when we login from browser. Login page would give these parameters to welcome page

Comment: @imox thanks you're right. i found a shortcut btw, no need for password at all `r = ssn.post('http://pythonscraping.com/pages/cookies/welcome.php', headers={'Cookie':"loggedin=1"})` :-))